# Automatically display different HTML code in different directories

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress page. In header I have a link that need to be replaced with some other link while user visit specific directory.

I need to find a rule that automatically detects current page's URL and display different piece of code.

For example: on main directory `example.com/` it would display the link with english text:

```
<a href="abcd" class="xyz">EN</a>
```

but when it's a language version directory `example.com/es/` (`/es/` or anything deeper in the structure like `/es/something/` or even `/es/something/something/`) it would replace this piece of HTML code from above with something else, like this:

```
<a href="es/abcd" class="xyz">ES</a>
```

Comment: use `session` or `cookie`

Comment: So what is the question? Where are you stuck? The question is currently too unfocused and broad. We have no idea how your website is built. Are you using the front controller pattern with a router? Are you linking directly to the files? Are you using any rewrite rules? Also, do you actually have URL's like `/.../`, or is it just an example where the dots are actually something else?

Comment: It's a Wordpress page